# removing arrow from select control not working in IE mode from Edge browser on asp.net content page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, select

CSS part for removing arrow

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

ASP Page where select control inside UpdatePanel

```
<asp:Content ID="Content123" ContentPlaceHolderID="navig" Runat="Server">    
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel123" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
                <select class="Dropdown" id="DropDown"  runat="server">  
                </select>
           </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>   
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not advise to use `::-ms-expand` because it is a non-standard feature.

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Browser compatibility
Historically supported in Internet Explorer and Edge before version 79.

Source: [here](https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Archive/Web/CSS/::-ms-expand)